# Tmux: Start a window as root?

Tags: linux, tmux

I currently have a shellscript which creates a session for me that has 3 windows:

1. **Zsh** - Empty
2. **Vim** - Runs Vim, started by `tmux-sendkeys`)
3. **Diff** - Empty

However, I would like to introduce a 4th window for root-business.

How can I start a window as root, either using `tmux send-keys`(I haven't gotten this to work yet) or some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this is probably a **Very Bad Idea**. Seriously, having a shell around that always works with root privileges is just asking for trouble.

With that caveat out of the way, you can do it like this:

```
tmux new-window 'sudo su -'
```

It will create the new tmux window and then prompt you for your password. If for some reason you want the password prompt before the tmux window is created you could do this:

```
sudo --validate
tmux new-window 'sudo su -'
```

You almost definitely want to change the name of the new window:

```
tmux new-window -n '** ROOT **' 'sudo su -'
```

But you really want to re-think why you're doing this in the first place, IMHO.

Comment: A bad idea in a work/office environment, perhaps. However, I am just a student on my personal laptop who is tired of `su`/`sudo`'ing up and down for every system utility. Regarding the rest, I think starting the script with `sudo -v` is what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Three and three-quarter years late, but for posterity: it would be a rather better idea to use `sudo -i` in place of `sudo su -`; there is no reason to invoke `su` when `sudo` can give you a login shell directly.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully set up a task in a server that creates a new session as root:

```bash
tmux new-session -d -s <your-session-name> 'echo "<root-password>" | sudo -S bash -c "<the-command-goes-over-here>"'
```